# Torsion points of an elliptic curve over infinite extension

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

How can I see that, if $E$ is an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$, than $$E(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})_{tors}=E(\mathbb{C})_{tors}=(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})^2,$$ and that $E(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})/E(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})_{tors}$ has infinite rank?

Comment: Do you know how to show that all torsion points of $E$ have coordinates in $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}$?

Comment: No, I'm not...do you know where can I find a proof?

Comment: You need to study division polynomials of $E$. They will have coefficients in $\Bbb{Q}$, and the $n$-torsion points have $x$-coordinates that are zeros of the $n$th division polynomials, hence algebraic over $\Bbb{Q}$. I don't know about the rank.

Comment: But why the torsion group is isomorphic to (Q/Z)^2?

Comment: That is easier to see from the complex lattice description of $E$.

Answer (score 4):

If $P$ is a torsion point in $E(\mathbb{C})$, then there exists $n$ such that $nP = 0$. But the multiplication by $n$ map is expressable in terms of rational functions in the Weierstrass coefficients of $E$, so the coordinates of $P$ must be algebraic numbers, i.e. $P$ in $E(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})$.

Now to see that the torsion group is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})^2$ is easy if you are familiar with the complex uniformization $E(\mathbb{C}) = \mathbb{C}/\Lambda$, since the torsion in this latter group is $\varinjlim \frac{1}{n} \Lambda / \Lambda = (\Lambda \otimes \mathbb{Q}) / \Lambda$.

Comment: do you have a reference to see why we have $E_\text{tor}(\mathbb{C})\cong\varinjlim\frac{\frac{1}{n}\Lambda}{\Lambda}\cong (\Lambda\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Q})/\Lambda$? only the last isomorphism with $(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})^2$ I got to understand.

Comment: I managed to understand the first isomorphism. It's only take $\mathbb{Z}$ ordered by divisibility as directed set and prove that the diagram formed by the inclusions $\frac{1}{n}\Lambda/\Lambda\overset{\dot{\imath}}{\rightarrow} \frac{1}{nm}\Lambda /\Lambda \overset{\dot{\imath}}{\rightarrow} \text{Tor}(\mathbb{C}/\Lambda)$ satisfy the universal property of the direct limit (that's not to hard). But I have no idea how to prove the other though.

Comment: @HeroKenzan map $\lambda /n$ to $\lambda \otimes \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: @HeroKenzan note that in this case the direct limit is just pretentious notation for union, since all the $\frac{1}{n} \Lambda$ live in $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 0):

The infinitude of the rank is somewhat subtle. You can see a proof in [this article of Frey and Jarden](http://www.tau.ac.il/~jarden/Articles/paper06.pdf) (see Section 2).